# Facebook canvas restraints and lightbox or modal

Tags: facebook, canvas, modal-dialog, lightbox

I'm developing an application for Facebook and would like to use a lightbox or modal to display contents larger than the permitted canvas area (560). I don't have much experience with Facebook app development. The research I have completed has given me very little information regarding the issue. Loading a lightbox is fine it is making the the lightbox wider than the viewing area that is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this, you would need to be able to access the parent element from inside the iframe but because the content is from 2 different domains (parent content on Facebook server, iframe content on your server) cross domain restrictions apply and you will not be able to.  So you will only be able to pop it up inside the 560 width iframe facebook gives you.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to achieve what you want, but I didn't get success because application called in facebook using iframe. And so that the effect of lightbox,modal or shadow have limited to that iframe width and height.

Simply, I am on conclusion is that the lightbox have not same effect which in normal websites.
In facebook it's limited to only canvas only.